# Apply CSS unless html contains a class

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply a style to an item unless it contains a class? Take this html for example:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="selected">Page 1</span></li>
        <li><span>Page 2</span></li>
        <li><span>Page 3</span></li>
        <li><span>Page 4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I currently have this CSS:

```
.nav li span{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    color: #777;
}
.nav li span.selected, .nav li:hover span{
    background-color: #deeaf4;
    border: solid 1px #2392F3;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    color: #000000;
}
.nav li:hover span{
    border: solid 1px transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

When I hover over one of the spans, how can I apply the second CSS block **UNLESS** It contains the class `selected`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, one way would be by utilizing the [`not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) pseudo-class, and attribute selectors e.g.

```
span:not([class=selected]) {
/* Quotes around the value are optional */
color: slategray;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gt78B/

Sadly support for the negation pseudo-class is limited to IE 9 + http://caniuse.com/css-sel3 though attribute selectors are widely supported

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem - because of browser compatibility - go for the ugly way. Toggle classes using jQuery.

Comment: oopsies - my eyes saw a massive fat $ sign in there and I went jquery mode! don't ask me why - guess I just don't look carefully enough. srry my bad

Answer (score 1):

With just css you shoudl be able to do this:

```
.nav li span.selected,
.nav li span.selected:hover,
.nav li:hover span{
    background-color: #deeaf4;
    border: solid 1px #2392F3;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 0;
    color: #000000;
}
```

This should make your selector more specfic and ignore the border colour change.